# having issue with my php code getting Error 500

Tags: php

can some one please tell me if these's a problem in my code

```
$db->orderBy('date','asc');
$schedules = $db->get("schedules");
```

by having these 2 lines on my page, my page shows Error 500
and if i test it on my computer on Localhost it looks fine and works perfectly.
and don't know if the problem is my code or it is server side.

Thanks.

This is my code to connect to database

```
<?php

$db_host = "HOST";
$db_username = "USERNAME";
$db_password = "PASSWORD";
$db_name = "NAME";

$con = @mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password","$db_name");

if(!$con)
{
    echo"
    <html>

        <head>
            <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        </head>

        <h1>Can't Connect to database</h1>
    </html>";
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: @RoAchterberg it says " HTTP ERROR 500 "

Comment: @RoAchterberg " PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function orderBy() on null in /home/admin/web/site/public_html/page.php:12\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /home/admin/web/site/public_html/page.php on line 12 "

Comment: Looks like $db is wrong / null. Have you edit your db config for your server?

Comment: @davidev i did not edit anything sir. my db is external not in same server. and i been using it since long time didn't this issue it just appeared

Comment: @davidev can you please tell me what is $db ?

Comment: @user3600217 Looks like your connection to your database as object. I would need more code.

Comment: @davidev sir, i have just added my connection code on my question check it out please

Comment: Thanks @user3600217 Why is it called $con and thereafter you use $db?

Comment: @davidev it is not database sir because even if i put the first 2 lines of php code in an empty page that i posted in my question , it shows that error. only that 2 lines shows that problem but on my localhost it works perfectly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208331/discussion-between-davidev-and-user3600217).

Comment: Please avoid using error supression. `@`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)